# CakePHP Notification system with jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp, view, notifications, components

I'm having trouble understanding the best way to implement a notification system in Cake. I'm using the [Pines Notify Framework](http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/#page) for the visuals.

I would like these notification to appear on every page so I thought a component that gets used in the app controller would do the job but I'm not sure how I would interact with the views from the component.

Basically, when certain conditions are met I need the component to call a Jquery script in the view of the current controller.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, when certain conditions are met I need the component to
>   call a Jquery script in the view of the current controller.

You know the difference between a server side and client side language? This is not going to work. php can't talk to the JS in the browser.

You'll have to use [Websockets](http://www.websocket.org/) or AJAX with long polling, [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to make the JS script communicate with the server through JSON to get the notifications from there.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was just having setFlash() call a specific notification view that threw the pnotify event.

Ie in the controller

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Something occurred.', 'notify');
```

And then in notify.ctp

```
<script>var stack_topleft = {"dir1": "down", "dir2": "right", "push": "top"};
$(document).ready(function() {
$.pnotify.defaults.styling = "bootstrap3";
$.pnotify.defaults.history = false;
$.pnotify({
    title: 'Regular Success',
    text: '<?php echo $message; ?>'
});
});</script>
```

This might be a sketchy answer as I am a bit of a cakePHP noob, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Instalation:

1) Include the turbo-tribble.js script in your main template:

```
echo $this->Html->script([
    'jquery.min', // JQuery is required
    'turbo-tribble'
]);
```

2) Include the turbo-tribble.css stylesheet in your main template:

```
echo $this->Html->css([
    'turbo-tribble'
]);
```

3) Add the snippet bellow to your main template:

```
<div id="turbo-tribble">
    <?php echo $this->Flash->render('tribble'); ?>
</div>
```

4) Add the `turbo_tribble.ctp` to the `src/Template/Element/Flash` folder;

5) Add the code from `AppController.php` to your `AppController.php`;

Than, you can easily use this notification plugin from your jQuery as well as from your Controllers:

```
// from jQuery
$('.selector').on('click', function() {
    // your logic here
    $tt.setFlash('Some good news!', 'success');
})

// from php
public function index()
{
    // your logic here
    $this->setFlash('Some notification', self::NOTICE);
}
```

More information find here http://turbo-tribble.ml/